# How do I export my text messages from either my Android phone, or from the Android Messages web interface, with the timestamps?

Tags: backup, sms, google-messages

This question is referring to [Android Messages](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging). For Signal and WhatsApp, there are either tools (or just copy paste) that allow you to export messages to a plain text file in this format:

```
[2022-01-29 13:43] Me: Hello
[2022-01-29 13:47] Other person: Hello to you too
```

Copy paste from the web interface doesn't work; that just gives output like this:

```
Hello
Hello to you too
```

I backup my phone to Google Drive, but that isn't browse-able. I can browse my phone's folders through Windows Explorer when I connect my phone to Windows with a USB cable, but that doesn't show the `data` folder. There are also solutions like the SMS Backup+ app that copies each text message to Gmail *as a separate email*, but that's not the right solution either, and is very unwieldy to convert into a text file.

`adb` solutions are fine as long as they work with an *unrooted* phone.

**Is there a solution here? I have a unrooted Pixel 5a running Android 12.**

Comment: Regarding the web counterpart, you might be interested in our sister site [webapps.se]. Feel free to also post on there *specifically for the web version* while linking to this question for the Android counterpart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SMSBackupRestore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore) can create local xml files in following format

`/storage/emulated/0/SMSBackupRestore/sms-20220130231717.xml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<!--File Created By SMS Backup & Restore v10.15.004 on 30/01/2022 23:17:48-->
<!--

To view this file in a more readable format, visit https://synctech.com.au/view-backup/

-->
<smses count="1" backup_set="51f3aa8f-9305-4a33-8b64-9bd0aa216060" backup_date="1643581068669" type="full">
  <sms protocol="0" address="+491749960000" date="1643272261991" type="1" subject="null" body="Sehr geehrter winSIM Kunde, die Abbuchung von Ihrem Bankkonto ist fehlgeschlagen. Bitte überweisen Sie die offene Rechnung mit Angabe Ihrer Kundennummer. Vielen Dank. Ihr winSIM Team" toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="+491760000443" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" date_sent="1643272258000" sub_id="1" readable_date="27.01.2022 09:31:01" contact_name="(Unknown)" />
```

If you visit the mentioned website <s>synctech.com.au/view-backup</s> you can copy & paste messages very easy
(beware of your privacy)

you can select all messages or just all messages from selected contacts or only selected messages in **one single** xml file and there is no need to send email or upload to google drive

---

[MyPhoneExplorer](https://www.fjsoft.at/en) can manage SMS (like eMail in Thunderbird), copy & paste or export messages into text file

`SMS Export 2022-01-31 00.26.txt`

```
Sender: +491749960000
Time:   Thursday, 27.01.2022 09:31:01
Text:   Sehr geehrter winSIM Kunde, die Abbuchung von Ihrem Bankkonto ist fehlgeschlagen. Bitte überweisen Sie die offene Rechnung mit Angabe Ihrer Kundennummer. Vielen Dank. Ihr winSIM Team
```

[image]

the whole sms database is located

```
%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\MyPhoneExplorer\<device>[<IMEI>]\SMS.dat
%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\MyPhoneExplorer\<device>[<IMEI>]\SMSArchive.dat
```

Comment: Is there an offline version of synctech? (Maybe that viewer is client-side only?) So I'm not uploading my text messages to a third party site.

Comment: afaik you can open xml files with libreoffice or excel

Comment: I can open it in a text editor too; that was the easiest solution. There is a lot of extraneous information there so it's not perfect (for my purposes) right out of the box, but nothing a little script won't fix. Libreoffice had trouble with it; opened it as a blank document. Probably some more fiddling I could do there too.

Comment: If you add MyPhoneExplorer to your answer (just so it's not only stored in a comment), I'll accept it. Just want that answer to be preserved as well because it's what I ended up using.

Comment: or just write a little parser with xmllint or xmlstarlet yourself

Comment: @alecxs [SMSBackupRestore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore) Is an excellent answer!  This works very well.

Comment: @alecxs Your welcome to join [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) If you have any questions about Ubuntu!. That's my home turf.